# How do I parse tags and attributes into a multidimensional array?

Tags: php

How do I parse the following

```
{menu id="123"}
  Random text.
  {menu-item id="123"/}
  Random text.
  {menu-item id="123"/}
{/menu}
```

into an array, like such

```
Array(
  [menu] => Array(
    [id] => 123
    [children] => Array(
      [menu-item] = Array(
        [id] => 123
      )
      [menu-item] = Array(
        [id] => 123
      )
    )
  )
)
```

It's similar to HTML. Tags that do not have a closing tag are self-closed.

Comment: you should format your string before parse it..see the JSON syntax

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @Sudip Pal, code cannot be in JSON syntax.

Comment: Without JSON, you should manually break it with explode() as a string and push it to array...that's the limit..

Comment: @Tushar I've done it the preg_match way, but I'd like to learn a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmh - if this is like html you could try and treat it like XML and use [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Lets give it a try:

```
$xmlData = str_replace( array( '{', '}' ), array( '<', '>' ), $sourceData );
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string( $xmlData );

var_dump( $xmlObj );
```

The resulting object might not be 100% of the structure you are trying to form, but now that's already much easier to achieve.

Looking forward to your feedback,
Have fun!

Comment: That is a great idea! Will try.

Comment: You'll actually have to deal with the text which is not in own tags - either wrap it into tags or remove it